# North Sea to Black Sea by own yacht

Tags: europe, sailing, rhine, danube

Is it possible to sail  from the North Sea to the Black Sea without lowering the mast? How far could I get before having the mast lowered ? What is the speed and direction of the water flow before getting to the Danube via the Iron Gates ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too technical for Travel and is more specialised

Comment: I would assume that you wouldn't have to lower the mast if you went via the Strait of Gibraltar, but I suspect that's not what you had in mind.

Comment: How are you supposed to 'get to the Danube via the Iron Gates'? I am not sure if your question really makes sense. No matter which way you go, the height of your mast decides wether you have to lower it or not.

Comment: If you mean via the Rhine–Main–Danube Canal can you really do it by sail power?

Comment: possibly ontopic on The Great Outdoors?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Well, unless your yacht is something like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_(sailing_yacht)), which would need to lower its masts to fit under the bridges across the Bosporus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get from the North Sea to the Black Sea (or Aegean/Adriatic Sea) via inland waterways?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/how-to-get-from-the-north-sea-to-the-black-sea-or-aegean-adriatic-sea-via-inla)

Comment: Read _Sailing Across Europe_ by Negley Farson.

Comment: Also our [outdoors.se] site accepts questions about sailing.

Comment: @WeatherVane Most sailboats big enough to be called a 'yacht' have some form of engine power.

Comment: @DJClayworth I realise that 'sail' is a general term. "We set sail..." means we departed, not specifically setting the sails. I was wondering why the mast needs to be raised at all.

Comment: Happens every once in a while that a ship crushes into a bridge in the Nuremberg area of the Main-Danube-Canal: https://www.sueddeutsche.de/bayern/schiffsunglueck-in-bayern-flusskreuzfahrtschiff-rammt-bruecke-bei-erlangen-1.3157069 (German)

Comment: @BernhardDöbler I was supposed to joining a cruise ship on the Danube the day after that happened, except it was north of the bridge and we were south.

Comment: @WeatherVane masts are typically semipermanently in the raised position.  When one motors in a sailboat, one drops the sails but not the mast.  To take the boat somewhere that requires lowering the mast generally means first taking it to a boatyard and having the mast removed.  So it's not a question of refraining from raising the mast: masts are not routinely raised because they're usually already up.

Comment: Many of the bridges on the German part of the Danube are quite low, as are the ones over the Main and the R-M-D canal. They are mostly designed for barges, not sailboats. [Here](http://www.viadonau.org/fileadmin/content/viadonau/05Wirtschaft/Dokumente/2020/20200116_Danube_Bridges_int_eng_final.pdf) is a list of bridges, and their clearances; some have less than 6m.